# migrate from SaxonHE 9.6 to SaxonHE 9.7

Tags: java, function, xpath, migration, saxon

i have an xforms engine working on SaxonHE 9.6.0-10 and my tests run green. Tried to migrate to latest version 9.9.1-5 for the last two working days but with no luck.

Narrowing down the problem the first issues come with version 9.7 where i get compile errors for the classes:

```
net.sf.saxon.expr.Container

net.sf.saxon.functions.SystemFunctionCall
```

These classes seem to have removed in 9.7 but i can't figure out how to replace them.

When switching to 9.9.1-5 also this class seem to have gone:

```
net.sf.saxon.functions.StandardFunction
```

Tried documentation of changes on saxonica.com but did not reveal anything to me.

Problem area is a FunctionLibrary i need to provide all the XForms-specific functions. Code for that libary is here:
[XFormsFunctionLibrary.java](https://gitlab.existsolutions.com/eXistdbElements/exform/blob/9ada7dbf0481ba52c93cd1225049e1cf51677fd9/src/main/java/org/exist/fore/xpath/XFormsFunctionLibrary.java)

it's superclass here:
[XPathFunctionLibrary.java](https://gitlab.existsolutions.com/eXistdbElements/exform/blob/9ada7dbf0481ba52c93cd1225049e1cf51677fd9/src/main/java/org/exist/fore/xpath/XPathFunctionLibrary.java)

and well as my base function class here:
[XFormsFunction.java](https://gitlab.existsolutions.com/eXistdbElements/exform/blob/9ada7dbf0481ba52c93cd1225049e1cf51677fd9/src/main/java/org/exist/fore/xpath/XFormsFunction.java)

Any hints how to replace those classes or to rewrite those classes to conform to latest release are highly appreciated as i've run out of ideas - thanks Joern

Comment: Just curious, as you mention both Saxon 9.7 and 9.9, which XPath version do you want to use in your XForms engine? I think 9.9 will default to XPath 3.1 while Saxon 9.6 supported XPath 2.0.

Comment: I'd like to use XPath 3.1 if i can have it ;)

Comment: I should have probably have mentioned that my code still uses the net.sf.saxon.sxpath package so not the s9 API

Answer (score 1):

You've obviously been diving pretty deep into the Saxon internals, and at that level things do tend to change a bit from one release to the next.

The Container object was part of the implementation of Saxon's internal expression tree, and there is some discussion of the way this was redesigned in Saxon 9.7 in a blog post: http://dev.saxonica.com/blog/mike/2015/09/parent-pointers-in-the-saxon-expression-tree.html

The representation of system functions in Saxon was changed because of the change in the data model in XPath 3.0 whereby functions become first class values in the data model. Again, there is a 2015 blog post that explains the motivation for the changes: http://dev.saxonica.com/blog/mike/2015/02/functions-function-calls-function-items.html

Your question reads like a general plea for help rather than a specific request for information. That makes it rather badly suited to the StackOverflow protocol. It's probably better to raise such matters on the Saxonica forums at http://saxonica.plan.io, which are more suited to open-ended discussion rather than a rigid question/answer format. Having said that, you obviously got your code working by diving into the Saxon code and developing an understanding of how it works, and you're probably going to have to do the same again. Hopefully the changes we have made make your integration easier rather than more difficult.